# .NET OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider Multiple Login Routes

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

Currently we have a class that extends [OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308227%28v%3Dvs.113%29) which is used for web routes. We are adding a separate API, in which case we still want to use that `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class.

How is it possible to register two different login routes, and how can we distinguish between those two routes inside our `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` child class?
EDIT: I think I could compare the path via `context.Request.Path`.

I need to perform some logic in the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method that will share some logic across the two logins, but some of the logic needs to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the same login route, but for our app we used resource owner credentials (grant type `password`) and for the API we used client credentials (grant type `client_credentials`).